# File explorator with custom removal and copy functions

Tags: nautilus, file-browser

I am looking for a file explorator that have customizable move, copy and remove functions.

Which strategy would you recommand? Is there any file explorer with customizable commands or should I modify the source code of an existing one (`nautilus` typically)?

The custom commands should be GUI based: not interested in having a terminal in parallel to the file explorer for instance.

Comment: Can you explain what your objective is. Are you trying to block move/copy/remove? Or are you trying to do something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Thunar** allows you to add custom actions to the right click menu.

From the menu bar, select "Edit > Custom Actions". Then you can set a name and the command for your action. In the command field `%f` will be substituted for the path of the selected file.

More instructions and examples can be found here: http://docs.xfce.org/xfce/thunar/custom-actions

Unfortunately, I don't think it works with removable media in the sidebar. Only files.